# C# Linq Where on SQL User Defined Function

Tags: c#, linq

I have a *user defined function* in an SQL db:     `db.GetMovements(cultureId)`.

When called like this, it correctly returns 2 values:

```
var movements = db.GetMovements(cultureId);
```

When I use linq's `.Where` on a nullable bool, `Complete`, it returns **zero** values - which is incorrect:

```
var movements = db.GetMovements(cultureId).Where(m => m.Complete != true).ToList();
```

However if I change the above to:

```
var movements = db.Movements(cultureId).ToList();
movements = movements.Where(m => m.Complete != true).ToList();
```

Then it correctly returns a **1** value.

---

Why does using `.Where` in the first instance yield no results?

Comment: I wonder if the earlier query gets translated to `WHERE Complete != 1` in SQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

User defined function is not stored procedure. It has huge difference. It's like view with parameters, and `GetMovements` return `IQueryable`, so `Where` method will be translated to SQL code.

If `Complete` has value `NULL`, so all compare operations will return false.

`NULL <> 1` returns `false`

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191270(v=sql.105).aspx

`db.Movements(cultureId).ToList();` materialize values to .net objects, and `Nullable<bool>` works different:

`null != true` returns `true`

I think, your code should be like this:

```
var movements = db.GetMovements(cultureId).Where(m => m.Complete == null || m.Complete == false).ToList();
```

Comment: Have clarified in the question now that it was a user defined function.

Comment: Do you think it should look like that because it is a single execution / more performant, or another reason?

Comment: @Zze two reasons: it describes your logic, it can be converted to SQL and executes on server side. But, I can't say anything about perfomace, I don't know table structure, indexes and so on

Comment: Thanks for the answer / responses.

Comment: @Zze glad to help